# Walk me through the proof that the class of graphs is elementary.

Tags: model-theory

I am attempting problem 1.4.5 in "Model Theory" by Marker, but I am very lost in terms of how to get started. So to help me with the process I would like someone to show me that the class of graphs is elementary. Note I picked graphs because it is not included in question 1.4.5. My primary problem is I am not sure what it entails to prove that the class of graphs is elementary. For example, if wrote down the axioms of graphs:
$$\forall x \forall y ~ R(x,y) \rightarrow R(y,x)\\
\forall x ~ \neg R(x,x)$$

then have I shown the class of graph is elementary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this shows that the class of (undirected simple) graphs is elementary (in the language with one binary relation symbol).

This is because you have found a set of (first order) axioms which are satisfied precisely by graphs (in this language).

For some classes, it might be harder to find such an axiom system. It is also sometimes quite hard to show that a given class is *not* elementary -- the usual tool for that is Łoś's theorem (we find a set of elements of the class whose ultraproduct is not within it).

Comment: And just to clarify an even more elementary (ha) question, is it true that if you cannot write down all the axioms of graph using first order sentences, then the class of graph is not elementary?

Comment: @chibro2: I'm not sure what to make of your question. It's as if you asked whether $1+1=4$ implies that $6\cdot 9=42$. An elementary class is, by definition, the class of all models satisfying a given first order theory. That does not mean you can *literally* write down a full set of axioms of such a theory -- it is certainly not possible if the theory in question is not countably axiomatisable (and even if it is recursively but not finitely axiomatisable, it is quite a dubious statement)!